How to minimize youtube-data-api v3 query quota useage?
I have a code to get video urls given a channel ID that I get from the API as well, but the main part uses the requests component.
I tried running it on a channel with 3500 videos, but for some reason running it once or twice used up 6100 credits. How is this being calculated? I don't have more than 161 requests total and they're all simple search requests.
Usage graph
def get_video_urls(api_key, channel_id):
    base_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3'
    search_url = f'{base_url}/search'
    
    video_urls = []
    next_page_token = ''
    
    while True:
        response = requests.get(search_url, params={
            'key': api_key,
            'channelId': channel_id,
            'part': 'id',
            'order': 'date',
            'maxResults': 50,
            'pageToken': next_page_token
        })
        
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f'Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')
            break
        
        data = response.json()
        
        for item in data.get('items', []):
            if item['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
                video_id = item['id']['videoId']
                video_urls.append(f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}')
        
        next_page_token = data.get('nextPageToken', None)
        
        if not next_page_token:
            break
    
    return video_urls

Requests History
I tried minimizing search parameters or changing maxResults, but they don't seem to have much of an effect. Moreover the credit usage changes a lot, yesterday I capped after running it on a smaller channel twice.

The Stack Overflow answer 74579030 divides your quota usage by 100. See YouTube Data API v3 Search: list and PlaylistItems: list endpoints.

This question is similar to: Optimize query to YouTube API. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

YouTube quota is cost based YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator You appear to be using the Search list method. Each request against search list costs 100 quota points
The initial 10k quota points that you have is the development quota they expect you to request an extension when you need one.
Remember you can request a quota extension when you are ready

Gotcha, thanks for the help!

I requested a quota extension about a month ago only took about a week.

Oh! I thought it would take a while, thanks!

Pro tip show them some math to justify the increase you a looking for.

Will keep that in mind!

To reduce the quota usage consider using PlaylistItems.List rather than Search. You just need to use Channels.List beforehand to find the ID of the channel's 'uploads' playlist.

Ah, thanks! I was trying playlist items earlier and it failed but I will do so again.
